# Can someone explain me the use of --destination here?

Tags: c

I am completing my CISCO course on C and I got a doubt in the following function.

Can someone please explain me the logic of the function, especially the use of     `--destination` here?

```
char *mystrcat(char *destination, char *source) 
{
    char *res;
    for(res = destination; *destination++; ) ;
    for(--destination; (*destination++ = *source++); ) ;
    return res;
}
```

Comment: In addition to answers: if you are confused on what increment does to a pointer, search for "C Pointer arithmetic". Also note operation order, specifically in (*destination++) case, which has deference and arithmetic.

Comment: In addition to answers: do not do this in your code, use pre-existing system libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first loop is looking for the string teminator. When it finds it, with `*destination` being false, the pointer is still post-incremented with `*destination++`.

So the next loop starts by decrementing the pointer back to pointing to the `'\0'` terminator, to start the concatentation.

In the second loop, each character is copied until the string terminator is found with `(*destination++ = *source++);` which is evaluated as the loop control. Again, this will include the required string terminator being copied.

Comment: To be clear the answer to the OP's question is the 2nd paragraph above.  The `--destination` is the initialization of the second loop above that decrements the `destination` pointer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very complicated function for something that shouldn't be written so difficult.

--destination is a weird feature of C. I'm assuming you already know that `variable++` increments the variable by one. Similarly `variable--` decrements the variable by one. The thing is, when the ++ or -- comes after the variable name, that operation is done after the line is executed as a whole, when it is before the variable, C does the arithmetic first, then evaluates the full line.

For an example:

```
int c = 5  
print(c++)  -> outputs '5'
print(c)    -> outputs '6'
```

but

```
int d = 5
print(++d) -> outputs '6'
print(d)   -> outputs '6'
```

This is because in the second example, the increment is evaluated before the entire line is evaluate.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I can't agree it's weird, it's just a way to control execution order. Yes, overall syntax is cumbersome, but hey, this is C, nerd-people only :)

Comment: @Oisin I don't think the standard says exactly *when* the pre and post increments are performed - which is why the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior-in-c) about using them in the same sequence is undefined behaviour.